# select created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(iframe).bind('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var range = iframe.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var nodeText = $(range.startContainer, iframe).parent().html();
        var leftPart = nodeText.substr(0, range.endOffset);
        var rightPart = nodeText.substr(range.endOffset);

        $(range.startContainer, iframe).parent().replaceWith('<big>' + leftPart + '</big><p>' + rightPart + '</p>');
        return false;
    }
});
```

I've got iframe with some content, e.g:

```
<p>someText</p>
```

When i place cursor between "some" and "text", and press enter, i want it to be splitted into this:

```
<big>some</big><p>Text</p>
```

everything seems to be working ok, but I also need to change cursor position to the beginnings of this: `<p>Text</p>`
I know how to set cursor position, but I need to select that element. just `$('p', iframe)` won't work, because I can have multiply `<p>` items in iframe. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution without adding id or class to element. i changed this:

```
$(range.startContainer, iframe).parent().replaceWith('<big>'+leftPart+'</big><p>'+rightPart+'</p>');
```

to this:

```
var leftObject = $('<big>'+leftPart+'</big>');
var rightObject = $('<p>'+rightPart+'</p>');
$(range.startContainer, iframe).parent().replaceWith(leftObject);
leftObject.after(rightObject);
```

now i got both elements selected in leftObject and rightObject

Answer (score 0):

This is an unholy mix of DOM, which considers everything in terms of nodes and offsets, and jQuery-ish HTML-as-strings. The two do not mix well. You've misunderstood the `endOffset` and `startOffset` properties of DOM Ranges: they're not offsets within the `innerHTML` of the container. I suggest looking at [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) or [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) and refactoring your code to only use DOM nodes and not strings of HTML.

Comment: endOffset - Offset within the ending node of the Range. so actually in my situation endOffset equals startOffset, because selection is just caret postion. where am i wrong? by string of HTML you mean my raplaceWith()?

Comment: @Denis: It was `var nodeText = $(range.startContainer, iframe).parent().html();` that worried me. `range.startContainer` could be a text node (in which case `range.startOffset` represents a character offset within the text node's `nodeValue` property) or an element (in which case `range.startOffset` represents a node offset within the children of the element. For example, a value of 1 would mean the range boundary was between the first and second child of the start container).

Comment: thanx for the comment, now i understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Denis ,

Give a common class name to all of them , so that it will effect on the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a dynamic id attribute (or use the [metadata](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata) plugin) using jQuery to identify the split paragraph. And based on the identified split string place the cursor before the `<p>` tag. Do make sure to remove the id attribute (or some metadata) once you are done placing the cursor, so that any other splits or a backspace on the same `<p>` doesn't result in unintended consequences

Hope that helps

Comment: i like this solution, but after replaceWith('<big>'+leftPart+'</big><p id="caret">'+rightPart+'</p>') i cant select that element: $('#caret').length == 0 :(

Comment: @denis , thats why go with class approach , use both class and id..then you can use class name at the end.